# xcode/bash: Trying to redirect piped content to a file

Tags: xcode, bash

Hi I'm using a user script in xcode to do some work for me. The first part of the script needs to take the piped content of the selected file and store it in a temp file. Doing some reading on redirects I found this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/Users/derek/projects/Crema/Classes/CoffeeFormController.m.uncrustify<&0
```

My understanding is that it should take all the piped in content and store it in the file The Xcode user script is set to pass the Entire Document to the script so this is effectively storing the current version of the file, regardless of whether the user has saved it or not.

However I get this error:

```
/var/folders/yo/yoISLF-4EYqDjeiZTSIpOU+++TI/-Tmp-/B047C058-C538-463A-848C-158EB82DAAFE-3501-000033543EE408FE: 
line 14: /Users/derek/projects/Crema/Classes/CoffeeFormController.m.uncrustify: 
No such file or directory
```

Which makes sense because the file does not yet exist. The command should create it. I also tried using `touch` to first create the file, but then it tells me it doesn't have permission to write the file ?????

Does anyone know who to store the current contents of the piped in file in xcode user scripts?

Comment: Note that `<&` is for [file descriptor duplication](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_43.html#SEC43). The left argument should be an integer or nothing, in which case it defaults to 0. In your script, `<&0` is therefore equivalent to `0<&0`, which does nothing. Moreover, working with file descriptors still has to happen in the context of a command. In your script, bash is trying to execute "/Users/....uncrustify".

Comment: Hmm, still getting my head around this redirection of file descriptions. The `<&0` I found somewhere on the web saying it would do what I wanted, but I guess it was wrong :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat` reads from stdin by default:

```
cat > /Users/derek/projects/Crema/Classes/CoffeeFormController.m.uncrustify
```

Comment: Thanks, thats much easier than playing with file descriptors.